# ComboBox SelectedValue does not update when the property used by SelectedValuePath is updated

Tags: wpf, binding

My goal is to have the bound property `value` update with the correct value if the selected profile changes its `Name`. Right now it maintains the old value which breaks binding on serialization/deserialization.

My XAML;

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="120" SelectedValuePath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Profile}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox
```

My collection of selectible profiles;

```
ObservableCollection<Profile> profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
```

my Profile class;

```
public partial class Profile: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { if (value != _name) { _name = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); } }
    }
    private string _name = "[Default]";
}
```

INotify seems to be working just fine because the displayed `Name` in the combobox does update for any profiles listed when their name changes. But when serialized the prop bound to SelectedValue known as `value` does not contain the new value for `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Looks like `SelectedValue` is only updated when the selection changes in the ComboBox and changing the Name doesn't actually change the current selection thus no update. You could instead bind the `SelectedItem` to a property. That would contain the updated Name. Any controls would bind to `SelectedItem.Name` instead of `Value`.

If you must use SelectedValue then you could unselect and reselect the comboBox's selection (yuck!) or force the SelectedValue to update whenever you make changes to the Name property, for example:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) {
    if (!comboBox1.SelectedValue.Equals(((Profile) comboBox1.SelectedItem).Name)) {
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = ((Profile) comboBox1.SelectedItem).Name;
    }
}
```

again, not that pretty but it works. There may be a way to get the SelectedValue's `BindingExpression` and force the update but simply calling `UpdateSource` on it doesn't seem to do anything unless the selection has changed.

```
comboBox1.GetBindingExpression (ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty).UpdateSource ();
```